# Running angular quickstart on Mac

Tags: typescript, angular

I have downloaded the Angular2 quickstart app from git hub. I am getting the following errors when the running `npm start` in the project direcotry. I can run just `npm run lite` in the project directory and the application launches in my browser. I have tried running the command as sudo as well.

```
Pers-MBP:quickstart-master jokerfwb$ npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/jokerfwb/Sites/quickstart-master
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 

node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(74,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(59,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(34,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(12,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(13,95): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/facade/lang.d.ts(59,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(32,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(34,85): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(417,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(28,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser.d.ts(37,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(43,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(45,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(52,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/xhr.d.ts(6,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/testing/test_component_builder.d.ts(77,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/testing/test_component_builder.d.ts(137,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/testing/xhr_mock.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(68,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(124,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(183,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(26,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(106,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(106,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(59,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(9,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(13,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(61,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(102,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(107,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts(11,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts(19,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/mock_application_ref.d.ts(12,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(72,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(76,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(80,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(89,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts(10,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(59,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts(25,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts(33,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/service_message_broker.d.ts(33,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/worker/location_providers.d.ts(14,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(32,40): error TS7006: Parameter 'fixture' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/app.component.spec.ts(40,42): error TS7006: Parameter 'fixture' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/app.component.spec.ts(43,43): error TS7006: Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(2,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(7,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(8,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'browser'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(11,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'element'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'by'.

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jokerfwb/Sites/quickstart-master/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions that are listed at the bottom of that message?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before starting the app? It might not have the dependencies.

Comment: yes did all that the files are all present. I have node 6.2.1, npm 3.9.5, and typecsript 1.8.10 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpile to es6 instead of es5 and this error will go away.

Comment: This is a partial solution because it does not fix the problem for projects that es5 is a requirement which is still for many of the projects out there.

Answer (score 1):

`./node_modules/.bin/typings install`

I had to run the following in the project root directory. For some reason `npm install` did not install typings properly.

Comment: Another option is to transpile to es6 instead of es5.

Comment: i'll give the a try

Comment: post your answer as an answer and i'll up vote it. That work as well